# Can't dynamically change ImageView by code

Tags: android, imageview

I would like to understand, why I can't dynamically change the drawable resource from my imageView.

I have different use cases, and in function of these use cases I have to change my imageView. In my code I tried these solutions below, but I can't get my imageView refresh. It keeps the default drawable resource defined first. Here what I tried:

```
int imgRes = activity.getResources().getIdentifier("packageName:drawable/"+"my_drawable_name", null, null);
OR
int imgRes = activity.getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/"+"my_drawable_name", "drawable", activity.getPackageName());

imageIcon.setImageResource(imgRes);
imageIcon.invalidate();
```

And also:

```
imageIcon.setImageDrawable(null);  
imageIcon.setImageDrawable(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_drawable_name));
imageIcon.invalidate();
```

I'm in one adapter and I passed this ImageView from my activity to my adapter. And I'm doing this operation from this adapter which go the instance of my imageView.

So I tried to change this resource my_drawable_name but in both cases above, my imageView is never updated/refresh, and its image resource doesn't change. I have no error it just doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong ? What's the best practice to dynamically change a resource from an imageview by code?

Comment: where are you calling this operations? Maybe your code never arrives to this point. Can you show some contextual code please?

Comment: Actually I'm in one of my adapter and I passed this ImageView from my activity to my adapter.

Answer (score 1):

No need to append drawable directory. It is the default behavior of android to get best suited drawable according to device.

Try using following code:

```
int imgRes = activity.getResources().getIdentifier("my_drawable_name", "drawable", activity.getPackageName());
```

Answer (score 0):

try `imageIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_drawable_name);`